# scraping with rvest with different number of rows in r

Tags: r, web-scraping, rows, rvest

https://www.transfermarkt.de/alexander-bade/profil/spieler/31

Is it possible to scrape the whole table in one scrape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to get the table in one go with the flag urls included (left blank when there is no flag in the cell)

```r
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

pg <- read_html("https://www.transfermarkt.de/alexander-bade/profil/spieler/31")
row_class    <- "tm-player-transfer-history-grid"
header_class <- paste0(row_class, " ", row_class, "--heading")

dplyr::bind_cols(
  pg %>% html_nodes(xpath = paste0("//div[@class='", row_class, "']")) %>%
         sapply(function(x) html_children(x) %>% 
                 sapply(function(x) html_text(x) %>% trimws())) %>%
         t() %>%
         as.data.frame() %>%
         setNames(pg %>% 
            html_nodes(xpath = paste0("//div[@class='", header_class, "']")) %>%
            html_children() %>%
            sapply(html_text)),
  pg %>% html_nodes(xpath =  paste0("//div[@class='", row_class, "']")) %>%
        lapply(function(x) {
          unlist(lapply(html_children(x), function(x) { 
            a <- html_node(x, xpath = "./img")
            if(length(a) == 0) ""
            else html_attr(a, "data-src")
            }))}) %>%
        do.call(rbind, .) %>%
        `[`(,3:4) %>%
        as.data.frame() %>%
        setNames(c("old_club_flag", "new_club_flag"))
) %>% as_tibble() %>% select(-7)
#> New names:
#> * `` -> ...7
#> # A tibble: 11 x 8
#>    Saison Datum     `Abgebender Ve~` `Aufnehmender ~` MW    Ablöse old_club_flag
#>    <chr>  <chr>     <chr>            <chr>            <chr> <chr>  <chr>        
#>  1 09/10  01.07.20~ Arm. Bielefeld   Karriereende     -     -      "https://tms~
#>  2 08/09  01.09.20~ Vereinslos       Arm. Bielefeld   -     -      ""           
#>  3 08/09  01.07.20~ Bor. Dortmund    Vereinslos       200 ~ -      "https://tms~
#>  4 07/08  01.01.20~ SC Paderborn     Bor. Dortmund    400 ~ 100 T~ "https://tms~
#>  5 07/08  01.07.20~ VfL Bochum       SC Paderborn     400 ~ ablös~ "https://tms~
#>  6 06/07  01.07.20~ 1.FC Köln        VfL Bochum       400 ~ ablös~ "https://tms~
#>  7 00/01  01.07.20~ Hamburger SV     1.FC Köln        -     125 T~ "https://tms~
#>  8 98/99  01.07.19~ KFC Uerdingen    Hamburger SV     -     300 T~ "https://tms~
#>  9 94/95  01.07.19~ 1.FC Köln        Bayer 05         -     500 T~ "https://tms~
#> 10 91/92  01.07.19~ 1.FC Köln II     1.FC Köln        -     -      "https://tms~
#> 11 88/89  01.07.19~ TeBe Berlin U19  1.FC Köln II     -     ablös~ "https://tms~
#> # ... with 1 more variable: new_club_flag <chr>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Unfortunately the code no longer works, I think the nodes are different. But I don't know how to fix it. Can you help me again?

Comment: I get the following error message: "Error in names(object) <- nm : 
      'names'[2] attribute must be the same length as the vector[0]"

Comment: @dlwhch Can I just confirm that you have unaccepted my answer because it _no longer works_ even though it worked at the time you asked the question and the website has changed? And now you would like me to help you again? And what happens the next time the website changes?

Comment: I am sorry, I did not know if you get a notification if I just comment, I dont know stackoverflow that well. it had nothing with the changed website :/

Comment: @dlwhch it's okay, you can choose to accept or unaccept an answer any time you like. I will get notifications if you comment here. Have you worked through the code to try to understand it? I think the website in the url has changed the class name of the table, so if you change `row_class    <- "tm-player-transfer-history-grid"` to `row_class    <- "grid tm-player-transfer-history-grid"` the code will still work.

Comment: thank you for this reply, I got it now. I also changed the "header_class" to get the correct column names and it worked.  header_class <- "grid tm-player-transfer-history-grid tm-player-transfer-history-grid tm-player-transfer-history-grid--heading"

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way of scraping the table in one go using `rvest` and the `tidyverse`...

```
library(tidyverse) #specifically purrr, dplyr and stringr
library(rvest)

page <- read_html("https://www.transfermarkt.de/alexander-bade/profil/spieler/31")

rows <- page %>% html_elements(".tm-player-transfer-history-grid")

cells <- map(rows, ~html_elements(., "div") %>% html_text() %>% str_trim())

cells <- cells[sapply(cells, length) > 2]  #remove last row (totals, only 2 cells)

table <- map_dfr(cells[-1], ~set_names(., cells[[1]])) #first row is headings

table
# A tibble: 11 × 6
   Saison Datum      `Abgebender Verein` `Aufnehmender Verein` MW         Ablöse    
   <chr>  <chr>      <chr>               <chr>                 <chr>      <chr>     
 1 09/10  01.07.2009 Arm. Bielefeld      Karriereende          -          -         
 2 08/09  01.09.2008 Vereinslos          Arm. Bielefeld        -          -         
 3 08/09  01.07.2008 Bor. Dortmund       Vereinslos            200 Tsd. € -         
 4 07/08  01.01.2008 SC Paderborn        Bor. Dortmund         400 Tsd. € 100 Tsd. €
 5 07/08  01.07.2007 VfL Bochum          SC Paderborn          400 Tsd. € ablösefrei
 6 06/07  01.07.2006 1.FC Köln           VfL Bochum            400 Tsd. € ablösefrei
 7 00/01  01.07.2000 Hamburger SV        1.FC Köln             -          125 Tsd. €
 8 98/99  01.07.1998 KFC Uerdingen       Hamburger SV          -          300 Tsd. €
 9 94/95  01.07.1994 1.FC Köln           Bayer 05              -          500 Tsd. €
10 91/92  01.07.1991 1.FC Köln II        1.FC Köln             -          -         
11 88/89  01.07.1988 TeBe Berlin U19     1.FC Köln II          -          ablösefrei
```